# Converting expressions to "edges" for use in TreePlot, Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, pattern-matching, trees

This question is similar to this: [Nested list to graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43930/nested-list-to-graph). How to "flatten" an arbitrary expression, eg

```
expr = a[b[c, d[e][f], g], h]
```

to a list of key-value pairs representing Graph edges of the expression tree:

[image]

These can be extracted by applying WReach's exception-based method --> [Can TreeForm be displayed “sideways”?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32727/can-treeform-be-displayed-sideways):

```
Block[{TreePlot},
  t_TreePlot := Throw@Hold@t;
  Catch@MakeBoxes@TreeForm[expr]
  ][[1, 1]]
```

Giving:

```
{{"a", "0", "a[b[c, d[e][f], g], h]"} -> {"b", "1", 
   "b[c, d[e][f], g]"}, {"b", "1", "b[c, d[e][f], g]"} -> {"c", "2", 
   "c"}, {"b", "1", "b[c, d[e][f], g]"} -> {"d[e]", "3", 
   "d[e][f]"}, {"d[e]", "3", "d[e][f]"} -> {"f", "4", "f"}, {"b", "1",
    "b[c, d[e][f], g]"} -> {"g", "5", "g"}, {"a", "0", 
   "a[b[c, d[e][f], g], h]"} -> {"h", "6", "h"}}
```

(Why are they cast to String?) Note non-atomic sub-expressions replaced with their Head. Based on the above, and the rule: `({h_, _, _} -> {a_, _, _}) :> ToExpression@h -> ToExpression@ a` gives:

```
{a -> b, b -> c, b -> d[e], d[e] -> f, b -> g, a -> h}
```

TreeForm is a wrapper around `TreePlot`. `TreePlot[%, VertexLabeling -> True]`  gives:

[image]

Since the layout is different, `TreePlot` must be making use of the other components of the output of the Block above.

**EDIT:**

How do TreeForm and SparseAray`ExpressionToTree (see below) extract these pairs of vertices? "Proof of work" is to extract the position (in the expression) of each vertex along with the edges.

Previously, I asked how to extract these "edges" based on a more restricted example [Alternatives ordering affects pattern matching in Cases?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51463/alternatives-ordering-affects-pattern-matching-in-cases). Also tried `ReplaceList` but don't know how to map it consistently across all levels.

Comment: Related: [(11458)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11458/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although kguler posted an answer using a nice internal function that does this (almost) directly I find this kind of expression manipulation interesting in itself so I wanted to see what could be done without it.

```
expr = a[b[c, d[e][f], g], h];

edges =
  Reap[
    Cases[expr, h_[___, c_[___] | c_?AtomQ, ___] /; Sow[h -> c], {0, -1}] 
  ][[2, 1]];

TreePlot[edges, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image]

Or for the different layout:

```
TreePlot[edges, Automatic, Head @ expr, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image]

---

[A user](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/36886/user3240588) asked about non-unique node names.  Here is a *first attempt* at addressing that case.

```
tree[expr_] :=
  Module[{e2, edges, head},
    e2 = MapIndexed[head, expr, {0, -1}, Heads -> True];
    edges = Reap[
       Cases[e2, (head[h_, x_])[___, 
          head[head[c_, {z__}][___] | c_?AtomQ, {a__}], ___] /; 
         Sow[Annotation[h, x] -> 
           Annotation[c, If[{z} === {}, {a}, {z}]]], {0, -1}]][[2, 1]];
    edges = edges /. head -> Annotation;
    TreePlot[edges, Automatic, edges[[-1, 1]], VertexLabeling -> True]
  ]

a[b[c, d[e][f], g, b, d[e][b]], h] // tree
```

[image]

This very likely has bugs that will need to be addressed as I did it in a hurry and tired, but I think it at least gives us a place to start.

Comment: Thanks, nice use of Sow/Reap, and inner Alternatives. One issue, how to specify Head[expr] as RootVertex? Maybe using a function of Position[expr, h] (in Sow)?

Comment: @alancalvitti I'm glad this helps.  Regarding "RootVertex" does this do what you want? `TreePlot[%, Automatic, Head@expr, VertexLabeling -> True]`

Comment: this answer, as the others here, relies on the nodes being all different. it's not easy to see how to extend it to the case where e.g. b appears twice at different places. one would probably need some temporary node numbering?

Comment: @user3240588 Good question! I'll have to think about that.

Comment: @user3240588 Please see my update, and look for cases where it fails so I can try to fix those.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it's looking good here: on my examples i get the correct tree structure. no bugs found so far. the ordering within generations seems backwards compared to how TreeForm does it but that's minor.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative method to WReach's method is to use `` SparseArray`ExpressionToTree `` which produces the same output without string wrappers:

```
expr = a[b[c, d[e][f], g], h];
ett = SparseArray`ExpressionToTree[expr]
(* {{a,0,a[b[c,d[e][f],g],h]}->{b,1,b[c,d[e][f],g]},
    {b,1,b[c,d[e][f],g]}->{c,2,c},
    {b,1,b[c,d[e][f],g]}->{d[e],3,d[e][f]},
    {d[e],3,d[e][f]}->{f,4,f},
    {b,1,b[c,d[e][f],g]}->{g,5,g},
    {a,0,a[b[c,d[e][f],g],h]}->{h,6,h}} *)

edges = ett[[All,All,1]] (* thanks: @Mr.Wizard *)
(* or edges = ett /. Rule[a_, b_] :> Rule[First[a], First[b]];*)
(* {a->b,b->c,b->d[e],d[e]->f,b->g,a->h} *)

Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", {Center, Center}],
             VertexSize -> .3, VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, Italic, 20],
             ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> 400, 
             GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> edges[[1,1]]}]
```

[image]

**Update:** You can also use `` GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph ``:

```
eg = GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph[expr, VertexSize -> Large, 
   VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, Italic, 20]];
SetProperty[eg,  VertexLabels -> {v_ :> 
    Placed[PropertyValue[{eg, v}, VertexLabels], Center]}]
```

[image]

Comment: More directly: ``SparseArray`ExpressionToTree[expr][[All, All, 1]]``.  Also, thanks for showing me `ExpressionToTree`! (Again?)

Comment: @kguler, +1 - btw ETT --> ReleaseHold. But I'm asking how TreeForm (and ETT) convert the expr. I edited my Q to reflect this.

Comment: @alancalvitti Is my answer of no interest to you?  Are you only interested in the details of the internal implementation and not an equivalent method in top-level code?

Comment: Yes that works, thank you, I had to test on some expressions of interest.

Comment: Since 12.1 `ExpressionGraph` is now a documented symbol in the `System` context. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpressionGraph.html

Answer (score 3):

IGraph/M now includes `IGExpressionTree`:

```
<<IGraphM`
IGExpressionTree[expr]
```

[image]

```
GraphQ[%]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `Position` provides all the information we need to construct the vertex list, edge list and vertex labels to build our own expression graph (in case `ExpressionTree` or `ExpressionGraph` is not available in your version):

```
ClearAll[homeMadeExpressionTree]

Options[homeMadeExpressionTree] = Join[
 {"DownToLevel" -> Automatic, "VertexLabeling" -> Automatic, 
  "RootPosition" -> Top}, 
 Options[Graph]];

homeMadeExpressionTree[$expr_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
   {$el, $vlbls, 
    $vl = Position[$expr, _, 
      {0, OptionValue["DownToLevel"] /. Automatic -> Depth@$expr}, 
      Heads -> False]}, 
   $vlbls = Thread[$vl -> Extract[$expr, $vl, 
       Tooltip[If[AtomQ @ #, #, (OptionValue["VertexLabeling"] /.
           {Automatic | Head -> Head, _ -> Identity}) @ #], 
        #, TooltipStyle -> 14] &]];
   $el = Thread[Map[Most] @ # -> #] & @ Most[$vl];
   Graph[$vl, $el, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graph]], 
    ImageSize -> Medium, 
    GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> {}, 
      "Orientation" -> OptionValue["RootPosition"]}, 
    VertexLabels -> $vlbls]];
```

***Examples:***

```
expr1 = a[b[c, d[e][f], g], h];

homeMadeExpressionTree @ expr1
```

[image]

```
dsk = Graphics[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Disk[{0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 80];

Row[{homeMadeExpressionTree@dsk, 
     TreeForm[dsk, ImageSize -> Medium]}, Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

```
expr2 = a[b[c, d[e][f], g, b, d[e][b]], h];

expr3 = HornerForm[1 + x + x^2 + x^3, x];

Grid[{homeMadeExpressionTree[#], 
   homeMadeExpressionTree[#, "RootPosition" -> Left],
   homeMadeExpressionTree[#, "DownToLevel" -> 2, "VertexLabeling" -> Blah]} & /@
  {expr1, expr2, expr3}, 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are seeking?

```
expr = a[b[c, d[e][f], g], h]
boxes = ToBoxes@TreeForm[expr]
positions = Cases[boxes, LineBox[{x__}] -> x, Infinity]
nodes =
  Cases[
    boxes,
    StyleBox[x_, __] :> ToExpression@x, Infinity] /. 
      {t_Times :> First@t, Verbatim[HoldForm][x_] -> x}
Rule @@@ Extract[nodes, List /@ positions]
```

> {a -> b, a -> h, b -> c, b -> d, b -> g, d -> f}

Comment: No, for example that doesn't match d[e]. But also, How to extract it directly *without* using TreeForm?

Answer (score 0):

In versions 13.2+, we can use [`ExpressionTree`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpressionTree.html) as follows:

```
expr = a[b[c, d[e][f], g], h];

ExpressionTree[expr, "Heads"]
```

[image]

```
VertexList @ ExpressionTree[expr, "Heads"]
```

> ```
> {{c, {1, 1}},   
>  {f, {1, 2, 1}},   
>  {d[e], {1, 2}},   
>  {g, {1, 3}},   
>  {b, {1}}, 
>  {h, {2}}, 
>  {a, {}}}
> ```

```
EdgeList @ ExpressionTree[expr, "Heads"]
```

> ```
>  {{d[e], {1, 2}} \[DirectedEdge] {f, {1, 2, 1}},   
>   {b, {1}} \[DirectedEdge] {c, {1, 1}},   
>   {b, {1}} \[DirectedEdge] {d[e], {1, 2}},   
>   {b, {1}} \[DirectedEdge] {g, {1, 3}},   
>   {a, {}} \[DirectedEdge] {b, {1}},   
>   {a, {}} \[DirectedEdge] {h, {2}}}
> ```

```
%[[All, All, 1]]
```

[image]

```
WolframLanguageData["ExpressionTree", #] & /@ 
   {"VersionIntroduced", "DateIntroduced"}
```

[image]