# Agglomerate output to Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, cluster-analysis

I'm using the `HierarchicalClustering` package to cluster some data. So let's say I have this:

```
Needs["HierarchicalClustering`"]

Agglomerate[{1, 1, 2, 10, 4, 8}, Linkage -> "Single"]

(*
Cluster[
    Cluster[Cluster[Cluster[1, 1, 0, 1, 1], 2, 1, 2, 1], 4, 4, 3, 1],
    Cluster[8, 10, 4, 1, 1],
    16, 4, 2
]
*)
```

Is there a direct way to go from that output to an undirected graph structure?

The `HierarchicalClustering` package can create graphs as `Dendrogram`s:

```
DendrogramPlot[{1, 1, 2, 10, 4, 8}, LeafLabels -> (# &),  Linkage -> "Single"]
```

But I would like to use the graph functions to work with the data. Maybe I'm doing this wrong and I don't even need the `HierarchicalClustering` to cluster my data.

I would appreciate any ideas.

Thanx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data = {1, 1, 2, 10, 4, 8};
leafverts = Table[Symbol["leaf" <> ToString[i]], {i, Length@data}];
Needs["HierarchicalClustering`"]
clusters = Agglomerate[{1, 1, 2, 10, 4, 8} -> leafverts, Linkage -> "Single"];
```

Re-using [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51645/125) to transform expressions to trees:

```
expr = (i = 1; Replace[clusters, Cluster[a_, b_, ___] :> 
                       Symbol["cluster" <> ToString[i++]][a, b], {0, Infinity}]);
ett = SparseArray`ExpressionToTree[expr]; 
edges = ett[[All, All, 1]];
options = {VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", {Center, Center}], 
           VertexShapeFunction -> "Rectangle", VertexSize -> .6, 
           VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, Italic, 14], ImagePadding -> 20,
           ImageSize -> 400, 
           GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding",  "RootVertex" -> edges[[1, 1]]}};

Graph[edges, options]
```

[image]

**Update:** Several ways to get undirected edges:

```
Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ edges, options] (* thanks: xtian777x *)
```

or

```
Graph[edges, AppendTo[options, EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line"]]
```

or

```
Graph[edges, AppendTo[options, EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[0]]]
```

all give

[image]

Comment: This is working good enough! The only tiny change I did was on the edges variable:

edges = UndirectedEdge@@@(ett[[All, All, 1]]);

Comment: @xtian777x, i updated the answer with your suggestion to get undirected edges.

Comment: Cool, thanx! One question...why the leaves in the edges variable turn out as HoldForm of the original expression? (You can see that if you do edges//FullForm)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ClusteringTree`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClusteringTree) (introduced in M10.4) to do this:

```
tree = ClusteringTree[{1, 1, 2, 10, 4, 8}]
```

[image]

Check that the output is a [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph):

```
Head @ tree
```

> Graph