# How to get all leaves from a graph's specific node

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Let's say I have this graph (The code to generate the graph is at the end)

[image: sample graph]

How can I extract all the leaves comming from, let's say "cluster3"?, i.e. {100, 92, 87, 89}

[image: sample graph]

I guess I have to first extract the subgraph with "cluster3" as root vertex

[image: sample graph]

and then filter the result. This last part should be easy.

What I'm finding hard to get is extracting the subgraph. I tried using the Subgraph functions doing like:

Subgraph[myGraph, UndirectedEdge[_, cluster3]]

But I don't get what I want

[image: sample graph 2]

Probably this is trivial and I'm just not seeing it. Any kind of help would be super useful.

Thanx!

This is what I used to create the graph

```
Needs["HierarchicalClustering`"];

MakeClusteredTree[data_,leaves_,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=Module[{clusters,expr,ett,edges,optsGraph=FilterRules[opts,Options[Graph]],optsAgglomerate=FilterRules[opts,Options[Agglomerate]]},clusters=Agglomerate[data->leaves,optsAgglomerate];expr=(i=1;Replace[clusters,Cluster[a_,b_,___]:>Symbol["cluster"<>ToString[i++]][a,b],{0,Infinity}]);ett=SparseArray`ExpressionToTree[expr];edges=UndirectedEdge@@@(ett[[All,All,1]]);Graph[(UndirectedEdge@@@edges),GraphLayout->{"LayeredEmbedding","RootVertex"->(UndirectedEdge@@@edges)[[1,1]]},VertexLabels->"Name",optsGraph,ImagePadding-> Full]]

data = {100, 43, 87, 1, 49, 32, 79, 42, 89, 92};

MakeClusteredTree[data, ToString /@ data, {Linkage -> "Average"}]
```

====Final Notes====

The MakeClusteredTree function is completely based on [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55807/agglomerate-output-to-graph/55808?noredirect=1#comment160510_55808) (highest of high fives to kguler). I just changed it a little bit for my original purpose and another little bit for this post (I'm using more complicated data, huge trees and originally, I only visibly label the leaves. I changed the VertexLabels for this example so I can show you the names of all nodes.

Comment: Please post the code you used to generate your graph.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that part. I already added the functions I use and the data. Thanx for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First a question for you: is there any reason why the edges are undirected? Your graph looks like a tree graph to me, with a strict hierarchy. For this directed edges would be better.

We can switch to directed edges as follows:

```
Block[{UndirectedEdge = DirectedEdge},
 graph = MakeClusteredTree[data, ToString /@ data, {Linkage -> "Average"}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also change every appearance of `UndirectedEdge` to `DirectedEdge` in your code instead of the above. (Note that `Graph` objects are atoms, so we can't do `graph /. UndirectedEdge -> DirectedEdge`).

We can then use [`VertexOutComponent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexOutComponent.html) to find all the vertices below `cluster3`:

```
subvertices = VertexOutComponent[graph, cluster3]
```

> ```
> {cluster3,100,cluster4,cluster5,92,87,89}
> ```

From these we want to select the leaves, i.e. those vertices that have only one incident edge:

```
leaves = Select[subvertices, VertexDegree[graph, #] === 1 &]
```

> ```
> {100,92,87,89}
> ```

And just to be sure, let's highlight the leaves we've found:

```
HighlightGraph[graph, Subgraph[graph, leaves]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: very nice and clear answer...`VertexOutComponent`...+1

Comment: very nice! +1..

Comment: I'm using undirected because, with the real data, I'm creating phylogenetic trees and just care about the leaves after clustering my data. I didn't think of a reason to have a directed graph, but, it's my first time doing real work with graphs so it's ignorance from my part too. Thanx a lot for your answer! Super helpful

Comment: Oh BTW, I just tried this with Mathematica 10 and VertexOutComponent now works with undirected graphs.

Comment: I just looked at the M10 documentation, but it doesn't seem VertexOutComponent will give the same answer for directed and undirected graphs. Can you perhaps confirm this?

Comment: Yeah you are right. I don't get the same answer. I saw the updated documentation, tried it and only after filtering saw that I'm getting more leaves.

Answer (score 4):

I post this but Teake Nutma is the better answer.

Changing your code to directed edges:

```
Needs["HierarchicalClustering`"];

MakeClusteredTree[data_, leaves_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{clusters, expr, ett, edges, 
   optsGraph = FilterRules[opts, Options[Graph]], 
   optsAgglomerate = FilterRules[opts, Options[Agglomerate]]}, 
  clusters = Agglomerate[data -> leaves, optsAgglomerate]; 
  expr = (i = 1; 
    Replace[clusters, 
     Cluster[a_, b_, ___] :> 
      Symbol["cluster" <> ToString[i++]][a, b], {0, Infinity}]); 
  ett = SparseArray`ExpressionToTree[expr]; 
  edges = DirectedEdge @@@ (ett[[All, All, 1]]); 
  Graph[(DirectedEdge @@@ edges), 
   GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", 
     "RootVertex" -> (UndirectedEdge @@@ edges)[[1, 1]]}, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name", optsGraph, ImagePadding -> Full]]

data = {100, 43, 87, 1, 49, 32, 79, 42, 89, 92};

g = MakeClusteredTree[data, ToString /@ data, {Linkage -> "Average"}]
```

Collect leaves:

```
leaves = Cases[# -> VertexDegree[g, #] & /@ 
   VertexList[g], (x_ -> 1) -> x]
```

Functions to find leaves:

```
func[v_] := 
 Last /@ Flatten[FindPath[g, v, #, Infinity, All] & /@ leaves, 1]
hgf[v_] := HighlightGraph[g, {Style[v, Yellow], Sequence @@ func[v]}]
```

Visualizing:

```
hgf[#] & /@ {cluster1, cluster2, cluster3, cluster4, cluster5, 
  cluster6, cluster7, cluster8, cluster9}
```

This is exported animated gif:

[image]

Comment: Every answer is useful. Thanx a lot for yours and awesome gif BTW!